# CSV wont open C++ fstream

Tags: c++, csv, fstream

I'm trying to read in data from this csv and it will not open in c++ I have opened an xml file the exact same way with no issues. As you can tell I normally get the user to input the file path using the full path. Any help would be great.

```
fstream CSVFile;
    while (!CSVFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Input the full CSV file path." << endl;
        string FilePath;
        cin >> FilePath;
        CSVFile = fstream("D:\\Red\\reports\\OAP60001.csv");
    }
```

I have tried using direct file path hard coded and i have tried different locations in my directories.

Comment: Note that `cin >> FilePath` will read a whitespace-delimited string. If you plan to read filenames containing spaces, use `std::getline` instead. Is the CSV file open in a text editor or similar? Sometimes other programs can lock a file, preventing it from being opened in certain modes.

Answer (score 1):

I suck on English, sorry.
Inside the while, you are using an inexistent constructor.
[Here is the cplusplusreference documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/).
You need to specify the FilePath AND the mode.

An easy way to do that is not using the operator=, but the open() function.

```
CSVFile.open(FilePath, mode);
```

Just another warning.
std::cin stop read after first space.
If you think that in your path gonna be spaces, you have to use std::getline()

Comment: thanks but unfortunately this has not helped any other ideas?